# Coding a subtraction loop that takes in a list

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, subtraction

I am making a calculator and need a subtraction loop for the code to work. Right now it is scanning the list but only doing the first and last numbers not the entire list.

```
if(a.equals("Subtract")) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter integers one at a time in order");
        System.out.println("When completed type done");
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        Integer[] nums = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
            sum = nums[0];
            sum = sum - nums[i+1];
        }
        System.out.println("Your total is " + sum);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        main(args);
        }
```

Only subtracts the first and last numbers of loop not entire loop in order

Comment: You're assigning `sum` each iteration in the loop. Also, I'm not sure what the point of `sum -= sum - nums[i+1]` is because you're subtracting sum from itself.

Comment: Run the loop line by line to see what it is doing, if the logic isn’t clear from the code itself. You’re assigning `sum` at every iteration, which probably isn’t what you want. And the line `sum -= sum - nums[i+1]` doesn’t seem rational because it basically means `sum = sum + nums[i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.
Move the assignment of the first value outside the loop and start the loop from the second element of the array (index=1):

```
sum = nums[0];
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum = sum - nums[i];
}
```

EDIT: Thanks Joakim for your remark. Fixed the end condition in the for loop

Comment: This doesn't generate the correct result for obvious reasons. Please test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-initializing `sum` on each iteration of the loop, to the value of the first element:

```
sum = nums[0];
```

You should do this before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Java 8 streams is not what OP is after but for completeness here is a way to make use of the List instead of a for loop using streams

```
if (!list.isEmpty) {
    sum = list.get(0) - list.subList(1, list.size()).stream().reduce(0,Integer::sum);
}
```

If a loop is prefered then at least use the list already created

```
sum = list.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sum -= list.get(i);
}
```